# Rewrite recipient mail queued in postfix

Tags: postfix

I want to rewrite the recipient adress of a mail queued in a hold queue.

Is it possible to rewrite the mail by hand with the mail id in the postfix queue ?

Maybe a command like this :

postrewrite -I ETGH12DD newrecipient@domain.com

Thanks for yours answers.

Answer (score 0):

postcat -q ETGH12DD | grep -v "^*** " | sendmail -oi newrecipient@domain.com ; done

I still have some encoding problems.